# How do I convert this math to php?

Tags: php, math, pow

I am trying to convert this math function into PHP:

```
(1.055^L + 8 + 1.055^(L^1.085)) * 900
```

L is a variable.

I have tried this, the syntax is incorrect somewhere but I can't figure out.

```
(pow(1.055, $L) + 8 + pow(1.055, (1.085, $L))) * 900;
```

EDIT: The answers return `INF`. The desired output, if `$L` is 150 for example would be:

```
199 599 037,495903
```

Comment: change `pow(1.055, (1.085, $L))` to `pow(1.055, pow(1.085, $L))`

Comment: Please do not vandalize your posts. By posting on the Stack Exchange network, you've granted a non-revocable right for SE to distribute that content (under the [CC BY-SA 3.0 license](https://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/3.0/)). By SE policy, any vandalism will be reverted. If you would like to disassociate this post from your account, see [What is the proper route for a disassociation request?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/323395/3524982)

Answer (score 0):

You are missing the `pow` before `(1.085, $L)`, this will work :

```
(pow(1.055, $L) + 8 + pow(1.055, pow(1.085, $L))) * 900;
```

Answer (score 0):

Just missing a function in the second pow

```
(pow(1.055, $L) + 8 + pow(1.055, [missing function here](1.085, $L))) * 900;
```